# bit_count() function in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I create a bit_count() function in Snowflake similar to [mySQL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bit_count-function-in-mysql/), which counts the number of active bits in an integer?

Expected behavior:

```
select bit_count(1);
-- 1
select bit_count(3);
-- 2
select bit_count(4);
-- 1
select bit_count(15);
-- 4
select bit_count(31);
-- 5
select bit_count(32);
-- 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As bit_count() is a function in Python >=3.10, you can write a Python UDF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY FUNCTION bit_count(input_int_py INTEGER)
  returns int
  language python
  runtime_version = '3.10'
  handler = 'bit_count_py'
as
$$
def bit_count_py(input_int: int):
  return input_int.bit_count()
$$
;
```

```
select bit_count(1), bit_count(15), bit_count(16), bit_count(31), bit_count(36), bit_count(127);
--1,4,1,5,2,7
```

Answer (score 1):

well if you just want the 8bit numbers you can just check each bit and sum those:

```
select $1 as val,
    getbit(val,0)+getbit(val,1)+getbit(val,2)+getbit(val,3)+
    getbit(val,4)+getbit(val,5)+getbit(val,6)+getbit(val,7) as bit_count
from values
    (1),(3),(4),(15),(31),(32);
```

gives:

| VAL | BIT_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 15 | 4 |
| 31 | 5 |
| 32 | 1 |

sure this is gross for 32bit or 64bit numbers, perhaps.. but it is a pure SQL option.

Comment: Is a pure SQL UDF faster in performance than a Python UDF?

Comment: As with everything. Test on your data. I suggest a pure SQL option, as some people have issues using non-direct SQL options, perhaps a tool cannot handle the syntax, I am not sure. So just posting options.